# Unsupported operation: Unsupported platform: android - Flutter + Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: flutter, firebase-admin

During my integration of Firebase_admin into my Flutter project in android, I have encountered an error message ‘Unsupported operation: Unsupported platform: android’.

I was planning to delete a user from Firebase Authentication as an admin if the user loses access to the system. I have used other Cloud Firebase functions throughout the app. I only need the Firebase_admin implementation in order to delete the user. Because, as per my research, I am only able to delete a user from Firebase Auth from the Admin SDK.

Is there any fix for the error message I have encountered ?? or Is there any other mechanism for implementing user deletion from Firebase Auth ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure you don't need Firebase Admin to delete a user. In the documentation of the `firebase_auth` pub.dev package, there's a FirebaseUser#delete method that you can learn more about [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseUser/delete.html).

Comment: I have seen the documentation but it is used to delete the current signed user. What I need is, deleting any user as an admin by passing the user id.